# Problem installing additional packages in ns2

Tags: networking, ns2

```
Step 3: Building the Dependencies 
Package autoconf is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Unable to locate package build-essential
E: Package 'autoconf' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package automake
E: Unable to locate package libxmu-de
```

**Source:** https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/ns2-network-simulator-on-ubuntu-14.04/

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ns2 build prerequisites :

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install g++ autoconf make libtool libxmu-dev

     ## Older Ubuntu's : libtool-bin
```

( `build-essential` will install g++, make. Easier to type just `g++ make` )

Also useful : `sudo apt-get install xgraph`

NAM : http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/ns-stop-couldn%27t-execute-nam-permission-denied-while-executing-exec-nam-4175524760/#2